# any example for MITK ray casting with ambient occlusion ?

Tags: visual-studio, vtk, raycasting, mitk

please how to run Modules/Core/src/Rendering/mitkVolumeDataVtkMapper3D.cpp in visual c++ 2013
also does ambient occlusion exist in MITK and if it is i want some example please
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't that clear. What research have you done and what in particular are you stuck on?